# Layer-backed view jumps to front automatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, nsview

My window has two `NSView` instances. So the two views are siblings.
The view in the background should be layer-backed, whereas the one in the front should not.

Once I set the background-view to be layer-backed, it automatically jumps to the front.

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
```

---

I know that I can solve this issue by layer-backing the content-view of the window, but since I'm using controls like `NSTableView`, which behave poorly when layer-backed, this is not an option.

Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: One MainView with 2 subviews. Your table view is one of the child view. You dont want the other child to come in front. is it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The table view is another subview of the foreground-view. I want to use `CALayer.filters` on the background, which then jumps to the front and covers the foreground-view, which is bad.